# How to make a backpressed action for navigating to the previous fragment in activity that implement bottom navbar?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I wanna make an application that has multiple screens (screen1, screen2, and screen3), and for navigating between screens I wanna use bottom navigation bar. I wanna make it like Instagram app that can navigate back to the previous screen when the back button is pressed. I have made an app with navbar but when I press the back button the application is closed directly even after I navigate to other screen.

Comment: you can use bottom navigation with a fragment container inside the activity

Comment: I did it but every time I press back button the application is closed directly

Comment: Then you can either add fragments to back stack entry then back pressing will pop them one by one, or override onbackpressed method in activity and handle it on your own.
Note: - Adding fragments to back stack entry will be hard to maintain

Answer (score 0):

Override the onBackPressed() method of your activity, and write back button logic on it.